# Parallax background won't orient a portrait any way other than on it's side

Tags: css, html

I have an image that I'm trying to use for my initial parallax styled background that won't change orientation. It's the proper aspect ratio for a portrait, but no way I edit the code or the image itself it won't stop turning.

I've tried using translate code in my css, and I've tried the whole z-index and webkit lines and I eventually learned that those wouldn't work anyways. I don't know what else to try.

```
            .parallax1 { 
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("me.jpg");

      /* Set a specific height */
      height: 600px; 
      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

The expected outcome is supposed to be landscape oriented version of a portrait of me. The aspect ratio is correct for this type of image but the photo still stretches and turns portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create a JSFiddle to demonstrate this, but it's most likely your `background-size: cover;` value for background property ensures that the image will fill your whole container while preserving the aspect ratio. Because you only defined a height on your container your width is naturally "100%" (because divs are block elements). If your viewport or the container's parent ends up more wide than narrow so will your background image:

[image]
https://jsfiddle.net/w4x3bq61/

One way you can tackle this is to set the width of `.parallax1` as well so it always have a taller height vs width such as:

```
.parallax1 { 
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("");

  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 600px; 
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 300px;
}
```